# Accessing a function in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a function to find out the "role" of someone. From this I then want to be able to log the users role in the console. This is the function:

```
  getUserRole() {
    return this.afAuth.authState.switchMap((auth: any) => {
      this.usersCollection = this.afs.collection<any>('users');
      this.userDoc = this.usersCollection.doc(auth.uid);
      this.user = this.userDoc.valueChanges();
      return this.user.map(user => {
        return user.role;

      });
    });
  }
```

I have tried doing `console.log(user.role)` however this does not seem to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Where does `user.role` come from? Is it a function? What does the `console.log(user.role)` output? What does "however this does not seem to work" mean?

Comment: It depends on where it is placed. Your issue is that the function never gets called and not that `this.user` is `undefined`, correct?

Comment: @Ravenous yes that i correct. This is placed inside a .service. When i console.log(this.user) nothing appears.

Comment: Have a look at https://medium.com/@nomanbinhussein/mean-app-tutorial-with-angular-4-part-2-4250522c845 to understand the flow between the service & your component. Not the best example, but it will help you troubleshoot the issue yourself.